# History of the macro 'in' operator in SAS

Tags: sas

I find the `in` operator to be somewhat confusing in its implementation.  It appears that this is due to the history of its implementation.  For instance, according to the [sascommunity.org wiki](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/MINDELIMITER_Macro_In_Delimiter),

> You may remember that "in" was not initially well received, so it was
>   disabled in V9.13.

This implies that a different implementation existed at one time.

Some questions I have are:

1. Was `in` implemented differently, in macro and non-macro contexts?
2. What was used prior to the `in` operator in macros which prompted the creation of the macro 'in'?
3. Was `in` not implemented in macros because the macro facility wasn't originally a part of SAS?
4. Was the `in` operator implemented differently in a previous version of SAS (pre-9.4)?  If so, how did its implementation then differ from the current approach?

SAS's idiosyncrasies often appear dictated more by historical happenstance than through objective reasoning or design.  It seems to me that having such historical knowledge would assist in understanding the SAS language and systems.

Comment: That article refers to the `%in` operator.  Previously there was no equivalent of an `in` operator in the macro language.  My guess is it wasn't well received because the syntax was terrible and dissimilar to regular `in` statement syntax.

Comment: Are you saying that at one time SAS implemented a `%in` operator?  Because with the current `minoperator` option, the syntax which is used is `in` without the macro token `%`.  Using `%in` generates a note, a warning, and does not execute the expected operation.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't intending to say that, I was just trying to clearly distinguish between the macro `in` operator and the regular `in` operator

Comment: Sorry Lorem but this isn't really the sort of thing you would ask here.  You could ask questions like this in Communities.sas.com, I suppose, but honestly I don't know you'll get exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I've found, with a bit of digging:

1. No differences as far as I'm aware, except for the macro version not requiring quotes.
2. People wrote their own macros to do the job. `%sysfunc(indexw(list to search,word))` seems to have been a popular implementation.
3. I have no idea why this particular operator was initially left out of the macro language. Plenty of other operators and their mnemonics have worked perfectly well in both macro and non-macro contexts without any bother ever since the macro language was released. You would need to ask the original macro language developers.
4. As far as I can tell, the history is as follows:

   - Pre-9.0: `in` and `#` were not implemented in the SAS macro language. Users might have written their own `%in` macros.
   - In 9.0 `in` and `#` were implemented in the SAS macro language, *without any option to disable them*. In some cases this could have changed the behaviour of existing user-defined macros when handling strings that contained these operators - I suspect this is why this new feature was 'not initially well received'.
   - In 9.1.2 and 9.1.3, `in` and `#` were *completely removed* from the macro language (presumably this time upsetting people who wrote macros after this functionality was introduced in 9.0...).
   - In 9.2+, they were re-implemented, disabled by default, and we got the `minoperator` and `mindelimiter` options to control their behaviour.
   - In some future version (9.5 or higher) we might get a `%in` macro operator, as hinted at by the note displayed in SAS 9.4 when executing a (user-defined) macro named `%in`:

     > NOTE: %IN will become a reserved keyword of the SAS Macro Language in a future release of the SAS System.  Changing the name of 
     >   this macro will avoid future conflicts.

Comment: To make your first point explicit, do you mean the difference such as with `data _null_; if 'foo' in ('foo') then put 'bar'; run;` versus `%macro Test()/minoperator; %if foo in (foo) %then %put bar; %mend; %Test();`, where the distinction is that `foo` in the former must be in quotes whereas the latter it does not?

Comment: Yes, just like the rest of the macro language.

Comment: Exactly, 1 is common across the macro language not just the IN operator. IN() isn't an operator that's available in many other languages or systems so having it in the first place was a nice feature. Most languages require you to use multiple OR conditions or may have their own different implementations.